Publications that relate psychologism to subjectivism?
In my opinion, subjectivism, being an epistemological stance that makes all knowledge relative to a subject (its extreme form being skepticism), is closely linked to 'psychologism,' understood as that nineteenth-century project that reduces logical truths to individual psychic acts, criticized by Frege and Husserl among others.
Is there any publication that links either subjectivism with psychologism, or individualism with psychologism?

Reducing psychologism to relativism (your "subjectivism") was the centerpiece of Husserl's critique, see SEP:"Husserl contends that all forms of psychologism are forms of ‘species relativism’, more precisely ‘anthropologism’. And he goes on to argue that such relativism is ‘absurd’." However, psychology much advanced since Husserl's time beyond "individual acts" and his arguments are no longer considered credible.

@Conifold Thank you. I personally think that Husserl's criticism is still valid, but that's another topic.
